Media files not showing up in Library running on Plex media server on proxmox lxc
I installed Plex Media Server on an ubuntu 22.04 lxc and Open Media Vault on a Debian 12 LXC. I created a shared folder in Open Media Vault by creating an EXT4 file system, then creating a shared folder in there and sharing it over NFS and CIFS. I used this tutorial. But that didn't work for some reason, I tried to directly mount the shared drive using NFS in the lxc plex container by
mount -t nfs <ipaddress>:/videos ~/videos but that mounts the shared drive and I can see the contents and everything, but when I add that directory to plex library, I don't see any videos or any media. I changed the ownership and group to plex, gave it read/write. But none of this has worked. I am confused on how to get the media working in the plex container.
